# Zero Sized Reply: Squid did not receive any data for this request

Tags: google-chrome, localhost, squid

I'm getting this:-

```
            The requested URL could not be retrieved

            While trying to retrieve the URL: http://localhost:8080/?

            The following error was encountered:

            Zero Sized Reply
            Squid did not receive any data for this request.

            Your cache administrator is internet. 
            Generated Thu, 12 Jun 2014 06:35:51 GMT by Uranus_BLR (squid)
```

I'm trying to run a web application using eclipse IDE. Only **chrome (im using *Version 34.0.1825.4*)** is displaying this error  **other browsers** are fine, they works normally.
I pinged the localhost.

Following are the ping command's console logs:-

```
                Reply from 127.0.0.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128
            Reply from 127.0.0.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128
            Reply from 127.0.0.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128
            Reply from 127.0.0.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128

            Ping statistics for 127.0.0.1:
                Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
            Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
                Minimum = 0ms, Maximum = 0ms, Average = 0ms
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**This can be solved by making a *host entry* and uncheck the *autiomatically detect settings* :**

```
remove ipv6 localhost entry ::1 with ipv4 127.0.0.1 
  e.g >>  127.0.0.1  localhost 
[ path to host file is :: C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc]

Goto  internet options > connection > LAN settings and uncheck the automatically detect settings.
```

Comment: Why would you remove proxy settings for all connections?
Shouldn't the implications of this be explained?

Answer (score 0):

Try to add to squid.conf an option:

```
server_http11 on
```

and restart squid. It  solved trouble for me.

Comment: That directive is obsolete.

Answer (score 0):

User reported they were getting Zero Byte Reply. User was trying to use an https address via a different port from 443 i.e. https://google.com:4433

I added the port (i.e. 4433) to the acl Safe_Ports & acl SSL_Ports directives in my squid.conf file, ran squid -k reconfigure and voila it worked.

In your scenario of trying to access http on 8080 you would just add the line 'acl Safe_Ports port 8080' to your squid.conf file.

You just have to be sure that you do not open a port that would compromise your security.

Answer (score 0):

Also I have same issue in my network for some of the Users. Luckily the web site was hosted on the local network, i just put this website to Proxy Exception. it solved my problem. Hop it will help in your case.